# PHP pretty print stop working

Tags: php, xml, pretty-print

I have php code that doesn't work anymore

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML($string);
$doc->formatOutput = true;
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

I've got error

`Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::saveXML() in /path/to/the/File on line 242`

I've got PHP version 5.2.14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [manual on DOMDocument:](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php)

> If called statically, returns a `DOMDocument` or `FALSE` on failure.

and

> If an empty string is passed as the source, a warning will be generated. This warning is not generated by libxml and cannot be handled using libxml's error handling functions.

`$string` is most likely empty.

Comment: So what do we learn? Turn on error reporting while developing! :)

Comment: $string is not empty but `loadXML` return `FALSE`

Comment: @jcubic does `libxml_get_errors()` yield anything? http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php

Comment: @Pekka it return empty array.

Comment: `libxml_get_last_error` return Entity 'rdquo' not defined. thanks for your help.